# use string variable outside of function (jsp)

Tags: jsp

I am declaring a string variable

String e2 = "'%'" (as I need a wildcard or an integer value for a sql select later on)

Then I have a working function which determines the selected value in a dropdown -

```
function typechanged()
    {

        if(document.getElementById("assettypeid").selectedIndex == 0)
        {
            e2 = '%';
            alert(e2);
        }
        else 
        {
            e2 = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
            alert(e2);
        }
    }
```

But when I try to access e2 outside of the function (and use it in a sql select) it is always null, whereas it is always the correct value inside the function.

I am obviously doing something fundamentally wrong, do I need to recast e2  as a string inside and then outside the function before using it elsewhere?

Any assistance appreciated (I am a newbie).

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

`JSP` is a server side language and `Javascript` is a client side language,you can invoke a jsp variable in javascript code,but you can not invoke a javascript code in jsp or other server side languages.

So if you want to use `e` in other javascript function,you need to defined it as a global variable or don't defined it(then it will become an global js variable automatically).

If you need to use it in your jsp code, you need to refactor your code logic or design

Comment: Thanks, though I did attempt to make it global (using <%! etc) but that produced the same effect (null), unless I somehow need to declare the variable as global each time I set it or use it?

Comment: since I don't see your full code,I do not know how to modify it,maybe you can put all the js code into one script and define a global variable

Comment: Thanks though already tried, e2 is fine anywhere inside the procedures which are all in one script but as soon as I go into a table (in the same jsp in order to run a sql select) e2 becomes null.

Comment: you need to use ajax to post a query

Comment: Thanks for feedback, ajax is beyond me so I will visit this at a later date.